# How to show table content based on selected dropdown menu in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

This is the view, dropdown above the table

[image]

this is the dropdown, i want to take the selected value to give it the table data

```
<select class="form-control form-select" name="nomor_pertemuan" id="nomor_pertemuan">
    <option value="">-</option>
    @for($i=1; $i<11; $i++)
       <option value={{ $i }}>{{ $i }}</option>
     @endfor
</select>
```

this is the table content, there are two check box for each rows, only one can be selected, and i want to check for each input, are checked or not which need the dropdown value, i tried ajax but it seems doesnt work because i dont know much about it.

```
@foreach($kehadiran as $data)
  <tr>
     <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
     <td>{{ $data->peserta->npm_peserta }}</td>
     <td>{{ $data->peserta->nama_peserta }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;" class="align-middle">
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ 'k'.$loop->iteration }}" value="">
         <input type="checkbox" class="{{ 'k'.$loop->iteration }} check" name="{{ 'k'.$loop->iteration }}" id="hadir" value="Hadir" {{ $data->{'pertemuan_'.$dropdown_value} == "Hadir" ? "Checked" : '' }}/>
     </td>
     <td style="text-align: center;" class="align-middle">
         <input type="checkbox" class="{{ 'k'.$loop->iteration }} check" name="{{ 'k'.$loop->iteration }}" id="absen" value="Absen"/>
     </td>
   </tr>                                                                           @endforeach
```

this is the table, if you see the column name, thats why i need the dropdown value to this

```
{{ $data->{'pertemuan_'.$dropdown_value} == "Hadir" ? "Checked" : '' }}
```

[image]

so what can i do to show the table data dynamicly from selected dropdown value, i need the value to give it to the table data as you can see $dropdown_value
i hope you can understand my explanation

Comment: Gak ngerti :( coba coba sini jelasin

Comment: jadi di tabel itu isinya kehadiran peserta mas, ngambil data dari tabel kehadiran, kalo hadir dia bakal ke ceklis di bagian hadir kalo gak hadir keceklis di tidak hadir, cuman buat ngecek hadir apa enggaknya saya butuh value dari dropdown itu dulu.

Comment: Ok, berati ngambilnya dari many to many, bener? Coba post data `$loop` nya, update di question

Comment: 1 tabel doang mas, nama kolomnya itu kan ada angkanya, nah dari situ makanya saya butuh value dropdown

Comment: Oalah.. Yowis, tunggu jawabannya. Ngetik dulu.

Comment: Ini maunya pindah otomatis pake ajax atau gak?

Comment: saya udah coba ajax udah dua jam dari tadi gabisa2 wkwk ga ngerti soalnya makanya minta bantuan para mastah di sini. kalo bisa ajax sih ajax biar dinamis

Comment: Ok, sambil nunggu saya jawab, mungkin nanti para bule bule udah jawab. Siapa tau mereka yang bener yah..

Comment: Gak pakai AJAX ya. Biar belajar hehe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, OP doesn't know how to implement checkbox with owned database structure using loop, and request using AJAX.

So, I tried to answer.

I don't have much time to explain about AJAX, but I do explain logically, so OP can implement using AJAX.

This is `pertemuan` dropdown :

```
<select class="form-control form-select" name="nomor_pertemuan" id="nomor_pertemuan">
    <option value="">-</option>
        @foreach(range(1, 10) as $pertemuan)
       <option value={{ $pertemuan }}>Pertemuan {{ $pertemuan }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

You can use it as a query string. You need to use jQuery events, or you can use AJAX instead :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#nomor_pertemuan').on('change', function () {
        var url = "{{ url()->current() }}?pertemuan=" + $(this).val();

        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

When selecting the dropdown, it will redirect to the same URL, but have a query string (based on your choice). You can query by retrieving the meeting ID (ID pertemuan).

And then, you can select the `pertemuan` column from the query string :

```
@foreach($kehadiran as $data)
<table>
<tr>
    ...
    <td style="text-align: center;" class="align-middle">
         <input type="hidden" name="{{ 'k' . request()->input('pertemuan') }}" value="">
         <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="{{ 'k' . request()->input('pertemuan') }}" value="Hadir" {{ $data->{'pertemuan_'.request()->input('pertemuan')} == "Hadir" ? "Checked" : '' }}/>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sip makasih mas tak coba dulu

Comment: makasih banyak suhu, udah berhasil